# How to get server file path in folderbrowserdialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

How can I show folder directory of the server file path (base on SQL server installation computer's folder path) on the client computer when I open `FolderBrowserDialog`.

I have the SQL server backup function and this function needs a directory for the backup location. So when I want to back up the database on server computer I need to show the server's director on `FolderBrowserDialog`.But now when I open the `FolderBrowserDialog` in the client, Its show the client directory.

Comment: You need to have your destination folder reachable throug a share path and look under the Network node.

Comment: Don't.  The user does not have permission to read/write on the server.  The user only has GUEST privileges on Server.  Put files on a Network drive that client and server both have access and users have the correct privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path via the `FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath` property

Comment: How to assign the path if I don't know "SelectedPath" ?.I would like to show all of the server directories in browser dialog.